# How to resolve html/js Calculator Not A Number (NaN) Error?

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, calculation

I am trying to display a percentage value from `((discount/price) * 100)` using the HTML widget of WordPress' WPForm plugin. My total output keeps coming up as Nan. Where am I going wrong? The Price ID is `#12` and the Discount ID is `#13`

```js
function calc() {
  var p = document.getElementById("wpforms-1365-field_12_1");
  var d = document.getElementById("wpforms-1365-field_13_2");
  return (d / p) * 100;
}

function GetTotal() {
  document.getElementById('answer_value').innerText = calc();
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="button" style="color:#000;" name="Get Total" value="Get Total" onclick="GetTotal()" />
  <div id="answer" style="display:block;"> Total: <span id="answer_value"></span> </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.getElementById("...");` returns a node, not value.

Use `document.getElementById("wpforms-1365-field_12_1").value;` for reading the input value.